# How to deal with web-hooks on travis ci?

Tags: magento, travis-ci, magento2, webhooks

I am writing E2E Test for a Magento extension(running on a headless browser). The extension pings a server that will send webhooks. That means that I need a public IP to run the magento instance so it can receive the webhooks.

Any tips?